# Wordpress - display child pages on the child itself

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have created a template that uses a side bar, within the sidebar I want to display child pages of the parent page. To achieve this I use:

```
<?php $children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');
if ($children) { ?>
<ul>
<?php echo $children; ?>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
```

This works as desired on the parent page.

When I am on the child page the side bar is empty because there is no children, as expected. Is there anyway that I can keep displaying the child pages, on the child page of a parent.

1) Click on main navigation link, takes you to a section home page - Child pages displayed in sidebar
2) Click a child and maintain the child pages in sidebar

The side bar is used across all pages and this would be required for all sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$post` object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) contains a `post_parent` variable which can be used to determine whether or not we're looking at a child page.

```
// Get the parent post ID, if we're looking at a child page
// Else, the current post is a parent post
$parent = $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID;
$children = wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of=' . $parent . '&echo=0');
```

Comment: Excellent, that's the one!

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to following,

```
   <?php
    if ($post->post_parent) {
        $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
        $root=count($ancestors)-1;
        $parent = $ancestors[$root];
    } else {
        $parent = $post->ID;
    }
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=". $parent ."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul id="subnav">
        <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

I hope this helps.